# Deriving a public key from a private key programmatically

Tags: wallet, keypair, address, private-key, mobile

I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place right now.

I'm developing an app with react native, and users need to be able to import their wallets via their private keys (and hopefully mnemonic phrases)

However, when I use the eas toolchain to build my app, I run into an issue with the Solana/web3.js package I was using to do this.

My current code is this:

```
import * as b58 from "bs58";
import * as bip39 from "bip39";
import * as solanaWeb3 from "@solana/web3.js";

export function deriveSolAddressFromKey(key: string): string {
    try {   
        return solanaWeb3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(
            b58.decode(key.toString().trim())
        ).publicKey.toBase58();
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}

export function deriveSolAddressFromMemonic(phrase: string): string {
    const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(phrase, "");
    const keypair = solanaWeb3.Keypair.fromSeed(seed.slice(0, 32));
    return keypair.publicKey.toBase58();
}
```

How can I do this without the use of solana/web3.js?

Comment: Can you update the question with the error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tweetnacl` to generate pubkey from the secret key.

```
...
import * as nacl from 'tweetnacl';
import * as bs58 from 'bs58';
...

export function deriveSolAddressFromKey(key: string): string {
    try {
        let key_pair = nacl.sign.keyPair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(key));
        return bs58.encode(key_pair.publicKey);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to add mnemonic support? I don't fully understand how mnemonics work, so some advice on that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I did not try mnemonic support. However, solana is using bip39 to generate mnemonic and I think you can use bip39 module. `https://www.npmjs.com/package/bip39`